# Outlook client for Dynamic CRM cannot connect to CRM in Azure

Tags: azure, dynamic, dns, outlook, crm

Hi: I have a Dynamic CRM server set up on an Azure VM.  I configured the web address for the CRM to be accessible from outside the VM.  When I  log in via a browser I'm prompted for credentials to the VM and then everything connects fine.  When I try to connect via Outlook I am not prompted for a user/pwd and the connection attempt errors out with the following message

"The caller was not authenticated by the service. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed."

Any help to the problem would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Dynamics CRM hosted in Azure is not a supported configuration, this is probably the cause why the outlook client is not able to connect.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this information? I cannot find it on MS website

Comment: @MaPi at the time I wrote the answer Dynamics CRM hosted in Azure was not supported by Microsoft. Now the CRM 2015 it's supported on Azure, more details on this white paper http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49193